# Send data from one fragment to another fragment in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to do an application with Xamarin.android. It is "ToDoList" and I have two tabs, one of them is to create and edit the chores(it is called "undone"). The other one is for the chores that are marked as done(it is called done). I have used Fragments for the tabs and what I am trying to accomplish is when I mark one task as done I want to delete it from the list in the "undone" tab and add one to the list in "done" tab.

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;


            var tab1 = ActionBar.NewTab();
            tab1.SetText("Undone");
            var tabFirst = new UndoneListFragment();
            tab1.TabSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.tabsContainer);

                if (fragment != null)
                    e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);

                e.FragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.tabsContainer, tabFirst);
            };

            tab1.TabUnselected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(tabFirst);
            };


            var tab2 = ActionBar.NewTab();
            tab2.SetText("Done");
            var tabSecond = new DoneListFragment();
            tab2.TabSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.tabsContainer);

                if (fragment != null)
                    e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);

                e.FragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.tabsContainer, tabSecond);
            };

            tab2.TabUnselected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(tabSecond);
            };

            ActionBar.AddTab(tab1);
            ActionBar.AddTab(tab2);

      }
}
```

UndoneListFragment.cs

```
public class UndoneListFragment : Fragment
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    ListView lView;

    TasksViewAdapter adapter;
    View view;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.undoneListView, container, false);

            Button addBtn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddBtn);
            lView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.TasksViewList);



            adapter = new TasksViewAdapter(view.Context, tasks);

            lView.Adapter = adapter;
            lView.ItemClick += Edit;

            addBtn.Click += AddTask;
            return view;
    }
}

public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
      base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (requestCode)
      {

                case 10:
                    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)   //Edit an already existing task
                    {
                        var replacedTaskName = data.GetStringExtra("new_name" ?? "Name not found");
                        var position = data.GetIntExtra("listPos", 0);
                        bool done = data.GetBooleanExtra("done", false);

                        Task t = new Task(replacedTaskName);

                        if (done == true)
                        {
                            t.TaskStatus = Status.Done;

                             //here I want to implement the code to somehow  

                             //send the replacesTaskName to the second fragment

                            //Your suggestion is here
                            DoneListFragment frag = new DoneListFragment();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.PutString("MyKey",replacedTaskName);
                            frag.Arguments = b;

                        }

                        tasks[position] = t;
                        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                        string newName = tasks[position].TaskName;
                        break;
                    }
      }
}
```

DoneListFragment.cs

```
public class DoneListFragment : Fragment
{
    List<Task> doneTasks = new List<Task>();
    ListView lView;
    TasksViewAdapter adapter;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.doneListView, container, false);

            Button deleteBtn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DeleteAllBtn);
            lView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.doneList);


            adapter = new TasksViewAdapter(view.Context, doneTasks);
            lView.Adapter = adapter;

            if(Arguments != null)
            {
                string value= Arguments.GetString("MyKey");

            }

            //click to delete done tasks
            deleteBtn.Click += DeleteAll;

            return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you have added the code to get the arguments in your DoneListFragment but I don't see you setting it in the MainActivity.

Comment: I need to send the data from UndoneListFragment from the `OnActivityResult` function because i need to send it only when the boonean `done` is true. That's where i have added the first part of your code.

Comment: So basically when your boolean from OnAcitivityResult becomes true then you want to send that data to the fragment otherwise you won't?

Comment: i edited the OnActivityResult to show you where i wrote the code.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to send only when the Boolean is `true`.

Comment: Then how do you think the onCreateView will be called after you have already initialized the fragment? Are you familiar with fragment life cycle?

Comment: OnCreateView is called then i click on the tab.

Comment: anyways, thank you for your time. I will maybe find another way around.

Answer (score 1):

For Sending data from one fragment another one simple step is creating constructor while replacing
the  fragment or calling fragment.

For Example:

Suppose I have two fragments ,

1. ActionFragment
2. ActionDetailsFragment

Now I want to send data from “ActionFragment” to “ActionDetailsFragment”:

In ActionFragment :

```
fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutActionDetails, new ActionDetailsFragment(Data x, Data y)).commitAllowingStateLoss( );
```

Now below code will be in “ActionDetailsFragment”

```
public class ActionDetailsFragment extends AppFragment {
Data x;
Data y;

    public ActionDetailsFragment(Data x, Data y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        —————————————
////———Here is your code———————
—————————————————

}
```

Now you can use “Data x, Data y” in ActionDetailsFragment…
Thats it…

Note: Data x and Data y both are imaginary variables..

Activity’s cannot use in TabLayout or ViewPager you must have to use Fragments .
You can use “Bundle” instead,

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your Fragment, retrieve the data (e.g. in onCreate() method) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

}

Comment: Isn't there any option like the intent and activities. I mean  `Intent.PutString();`  in the first fragment and  `Intent.GetStringExtra();`  in the second one? that's what we use when we use activities

Comment: you can refer my answer i update it, you can also use Bundle instead of Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for Fragment to Fragment data transfer the smart way of doing it would be using fragment arguments, Something like this:

- When you initialize the fragment object in your case:

  ```
  var frag= new DoneListFragment();
  Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
  bundle.PutString("YourKey", "YourValue");
  frag.Arguments=bundle;
  ```
- Then to retrieve this data you do something like this in `DoneListFragment` in the OnCreateView method:

  ```
  if(Arguments!=null)
  {
     String value = Arguments.GetString("YourKey");
  }
  ```

Comment: What do I need this line `YourNewFragment frag= new YourNewFragment ();` of code for?

Comment: that basically is the object of your fragment in your case YourNewFragment is either UndoneListFragment or DoneListFragment

Comment: I don't get it. Where do I need to write this. I mean I write the first part of your suggestion in the place where I have commented that I need to implement this functionality(in UndoneListFragment). And second part I write in my "DoneListFragment" in the OnCreateView and when I get to the `Arguments.GetString();` I get a null exception.

Comment: updating my answer in 2mins

Comment: hi I actually tried `frag.Arguments=bundle;` before you updated it, but it doesn't seem to work. When I debug it, it clearly says that frag.Arguments has a value, but when it goes to the DoneListFragment class it says that Arguments is null

Comment: i will add edit my question and add the DoneListFragment code in a few minutes

Comment: Yes do that so it is easier to understand the reason for your problem